# Zeno's Track Time

Tags: sequences-and-series

Alright, so I just need a double-check to make sure I'm not crazy.

Zeno's Paradox concerning the half-distances of travel is represented by the series 1/(2^n), which goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, therefore converging on 0.

I've been asked to figure out the time it takes to traverse a track. So if the series is written as a geometric series with R = 1/2, then R^n represents the rate of the runner. If distance = rate * time, and distance = 1, does time = (2^n)/1?

I feel like I went about this incorrectly but I'm a little lost.

Comment: Yes, you did. What's the rate? You didn't specify any idea that's even remotely close to rate.

Comment: Is 1/(2^n) not the rate? Because you move half the remaining distance per time increment. The part that confuses me is that the value of the time increment changes.

Comment: I though that the time spent running could also be represented by [1/(2^n)] and then multiplied by x, where x represented the runner's speed and n represented the number of distance intervals. If that was true, I still have the geometric series multiplied by x, and the sum of the geometric series is 1, which gives me a time of x. So I'm still pretty confused as to how to frame this.

Comment: "the series 1/(2^n), which goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, therefore converging on 0." The *sequence* of terms $\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to 0, but the *series* $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to 1. Moreover, a *sequence* of terms may converge to 0 and yet the *series* can be divergent. The series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time it takes to traverse the track is two times the time it takes to traverse half the track.  You can compute this two ways.  The first is to note that a given rate of travel doesn't change just because you can do (say) half a mile in half an hour, then a quarter of a mile in a quarter of an hour, etc.  You are still travelling one mile per hour at each particular moment in time.  The second way is to solve the infinite series, which will similarly tell you that you've travelled $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...$ of (say) a mile in $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...$ of (say) an hour, which adds up to one mile per hour.  The first way does the division at each term and the second way does the division at the end.

Comment: Ahh, I think I got it based on what you said! So if it takes t minutes to circle half the track, we have the series [1/(2^n)]*t. The sum of this geometric series is t/(1-(1/2)) = 2t, which makes perfect sense logically. Thank you!